# Solving $0<\frac{2x}{x-2}<1$

Tags: inequality

How would I solve this inequality?
$$0<\frac{2x}{x-2}<1$$

Any simple way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice, we have the following inequality $$0<\frac{2x}{x-2}<1$$
Now, solving by parts as follows

1. we have LHS inequality $$\frac{2x}{x-2}>0$$$$\iff x<0 \ \text{or}\ x>2$$
2. we have RHS inequality  $$\frac{2x}{x-2}<1$$ 
   $$\frac{2x}{x-2}-1<0$$
   $$\frac{x+2}{x-2}<0$$

$$\iff -2<x<2$$
Taking solutions (1) & (2) on the number line, the complete solution of given inequality is $$\color{red}{x\in(-2, 0)}$$

Comment: Can you please tell me why $$\frac{x+2}{x-2}<0$$

$$\iff -2<x<2$$

Comment: Alright, notice we have RHS inequality  as follows $$\frac{2x}{x-2}<1$$  $$\frac{2x}{x-2}-1<0$$  $$\frac{2x-(x-2)}{x-2}<0$$  $$\frac{2x-x+2)}{x-2}<0$$ $$\frac{x+2}{x-2}<0\iff -2<x<2$$

Comment: Nice answer. Could you please tell me why in the RHS inequality you didn't just multiply by $x-2$? If we did that we'd find that $x<-2$. Apparently this is wrong. But why exactly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Alright, we will get the same answer if we multiply by $(x-2)$ by specifying the points $x=-2$ & $x=2$ on the number line & dividing the positive & negative regions, notice  $$\frac{(x+2)(x-2)}{x-2}<0$$ $$(x+2)(x-2)<0\iff -2<x<2$$

Answer (score 2):

Multiply both sides with $(x-2)^2$, which is positive. If $x\neq 2$, you get the equivalent inequalities:
$$0<2x(x-2)<(x-2)^2$$

The left-hand side inequality has $x<0$ or $x>2$  as solutions.

The right-hand side is equivalent to
$$x^2<4\iff -2<x<2$$

The solution that is common to both  inequations is $\;\color{red}{-2<x<0}$.

Answer (score 1):

1) If $x>2$ then it is equivalent to $2x>0$ and $2x<x-2$ which is $x\in (2,\infty)\cap (0,\infty)\cap (-\infty,-2)=\emptyset$

2)If $x<2$ then it is equivalent to $2x<0$ and $2x>x-2$ which is $x\in(-\infty,2)\cap (-\infty,0)\cap (-2,\infty)=(-2,0)$